# Can you identify this low-wing, single engine aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Can any one please identify this monoplane with a huge curved exhaust.

[image: low wing, single engine aircraft]

Comment: I still think OP was mis-identifying the curved roll-over structure as being a gigantic exhaust pipe, with the black material of the cockpit "coaming" (rim) being mistaken for the open end of the pipe!

Comment: Many thanks to you all  for taking the time to answer ther question - much appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

I believe this is a Junkers T29, or something similar. This photo from behind shows that the plane has both a rollbar over the cockpit as well as a separate exhaust pipe that sticks up prominently from the engine. [Image Source](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Junkers_T_29&oldid=183887341)

[image]

Comment: Wikipedia says the curved thing is a  “longitudinal arch over their heads to protect them like a roll bar”   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junkers_T_29

Comment: Only two were built. More photos of the Junkers T29 here: https://www-airwar-ru.translate.goog/enc/other1/jut29.html?_x_tr_sch=http&_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp

Comment: The T29 was also a test platform for the doppelflugel, which is that funky double-wing control surface. Nice catch.

Comment: @MikeSowsun Nice find. [This photo](http://www.airwar.ru/image/idop/other1/jut29/jut29-2.jpg) appears to be the same as the one in the OP, albeit in better quality

Comment: What were they doing with this plane that made them decide to add a roll bar?  Were upside-down landings something they had to worry about a lot in those days?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: It's not hard to imagine an airplane of this configuration nosing over on landing and ending up on its back, especially when used in a training role.

Comment: @FredLarson : it was an experimental aircraft after all, designed to test a completely new type of control surface which has never been used before. The first flight must have really been exciting, not even knowing for sure if the aircraft will be controllable at all.

Comment: One might expect the exhaust to be contaminated with unburned fuel and sparks and soot.  Odd that it exits right before the windscreen, also risking carbon monoxide in the cabin.  Wonder if that's why it has the aircraft ID of the beast :)